# Strange electrical issues

Tags: usb

I'm having very weird electrical (i think) issues with my computer and peripherals.

If i rub my feet on the floor and touch the metal casing of my keyboard (Razer Blackwidow X Chroma) it turns off, disconnects and reconnects. My wireless headset base station restarts itself on random. My screen goes black on random. Mind you these are all popular brand components from the top shelf, not some random junk.

I have tried different USB ports, disabled USB power saving, tried other keyboard and screen, new cables, new mainboard, different USB controllers (Intel & ASMedia), heck, i even bought a power balancer from UPS. So many things are failing that i cannot believe they are all faulty and i'm starting to think its a power issue. Maybe grounding? I have a multimeter, is there any simple test i can do myself?

Comment: Have you ever heard of static electricity? It can seriously damage any electronics, if no precautions taken (just burned a motherboard in a lab few days ago while sitting with my coat hang on a chair...).

Comment: Are you asking if/why static electricity damages electronics!?

Comment: Umm.. this is a consumer product. Touching its casing shouldnt cause it to disconnect?

Comment: Have an electritian check the PE (protective earth) connection of your mains sockets. You can test your power cable with the multimeter for continuity - while disconnected of course - but the socket requires an expert with proper equipment.

Comment: Properly grounded consumer equipment is more resistant to ESD, but it is not impervious.

Comment: Dont rub your feet on the floor then!!!!!!! :D

Comment: "all popular brand components from the top shelf, not some random junk." - Do not forget where all brands made. Unfortunately even top brands trying to make economy by eliminating some electronic parts (I saw many lenovo, hp and dell that have missing capacitors or fuses even PCB supposed to have it). Get a decent  UPS and check if it isn't complain about incorrect grounding on that outlet you connecting computer. Anti static spray for your floor is also a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Mains fault to the ground

Your mains electrical installation is somewhere in your building leaking current to the ground.
This can cause **lethal electrocution!**

Have a qualified electrician check your mains installation and install a 300 mA (or better 30 mA) [residual current device (RCD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual-current_device), also known as a residual-current circuit breaker (RCCB). This is a real life-saver and nowadays obligatory in the developed world.

[image: residual current device]

Comment: Already have an RCB, will get an electrician.

Comment: @MaciejSwic It can also be current leaking in from your next door neighbour, if the buildings are built in a row. This happened to me and my PC not long ago. It ended with a serious fire in the neighbour's electricity cabinet.

Comment: In very old, unapproved electrical installations, [neutral could be connected to ground](http://www.escardio.org/static_file/Escardio/Subspecialty/EHRA/Education/EP%20Cases/Documents/2016/‘Life-saving’%20inappropriate%20ICD%20shock.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The effect you are describing is electrostatic discharge. Your computers response is to shut down and reboot. Discharge yourself on a grounded metal object before touching the computer. In winter it is very dry so increase the level of humidity in your home with a humidifier to lower the possibility of this happening again.

Comment: The problem is that the screen and headset reconnect even if i sit still and dont move after touching the keyboard.

Comment: Set your keyboard on some antistatic foam, (the black foam electronic parts often come on), and touch it (to discharge any static charge on you, before touching the keyboard. An antistatic bag may work as well.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your main computer, not in the peripherals you are focusing on. Apparently your computer does not have the proper (separate) routing for USB shields, so the ESD events (in dry-air winter time) cause massive bouncing of signal ground and massive disruption of digital interface signals. There is nothing much you can do other than get a better host computer, and/or spray your carpet and boots with anti-static, as "alex" has suggested above.